# Trying to migrate SQL commands from plain PHP using Yii2

Tags: mysql, yii2

I'm trying to change my PHP statement to Yii2. Here's the original code:

```
$sql = "select id from users where member_type='d'";
$max = @mysql_num_rows($r=mysql_query($sql));
for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++){
    $demo2=mysql_fetch_assoc($r);
    some_functions($demo2['id'], 'something');
}
```

I'm new to Yii2 framework and trying to convert it to Yii2 but have no idea how. I'm doing this function under a modal file.

Here's what I can do at best:

```
$max= Yii::$app->dbFxprimus->createCommand("select count(id) from ". $this->tableName() ." where member_type='d'")->queryAll();
for($i2=0;$i2<$max;$i2++){
    $demo=mysql_fetch_assoc($max); //this is definitely wrong, help me to fix this, I don't know what is the Yii2 function for this.
    some_function($demo['id'], 'something');
}
```

Can anyone help me to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all you need to build query and get the results.

**1)** If you don't have model, you can do it like that:

```
use yii\db\Query;

...

$users = (new Query())
    ->select('id')
    ->from('users')
    ->where(['member_type' => 'd'])
    ->all()
```

Alternatively you can build query with `Yii::$app->db->createCommand()`, but this is better looking.

**2)** If you have model, and want get results as associative arrays:

```
use app\models\User;

...

$users = User::find()
    ->select('id')
    ->where(['member_type' => 'd'])
    ->asArray()
    ->all();
```

Then just loop through and apply your function:

```
foreach ($users as $user) {
    some_function($user['id'], 'something');
}
```

And you need replace `some_function` to call of some method class, because it's OOP.

**P.S.** Take your time and read the [docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-index.html). It's covered there.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ids = Yii::$app->dbFxprimus->createCommand("select id from ". $this->tableName() ." where member_type='d'")->queryColumn();
foreach($ids as $id){
    some_function($id, 'something');
}
```

And if '$this' is an ActiveRecord instance:

```
$ids = self::find()
    ->select(['id'])
    ->where(['member_type' => 'd'])
    ->column();
foreach($ids as $id){
    some_function($id, 'something');
}
```

Comment: Code only answers are not welcomed on Stack Overflow. Please add some explanation.

Comment: May I know if I'm not using the "foreach", I want to use the "for loop", what Yii2 command can I use ?

Comment: @nodeffect Why for? `foreach` is more suitable here. And also it is native language construct.

Comment: There is no Yii command for common php functions. You still use for($i=0;$i<(count($ids)-1);$i++) and so on.

Comment: Why you need the number of rows? In your example it's only used as a limitation for loop. You just loop through and call function with user id as parameter. Please be more precise when asking questions.

Comment: ok, thanks... I just wanted to learn more about yii, just in case in the future I might need it...

Comment: I recommend spend some time and read the docs. And even for plain PHP your example is not optimum.

Comment: actually the answer from @arogachev is better, as he shows you how to use a Model. In your case this is the `Yii way` to go. If you want to learn Yii, forget about writing plain SQL

Comment: Pavel added the option with model too (after I told him that code only answers are not good on SO), but he didn't mention that this should be placed inside some method in `User` model because it's called through `self`. Also it's recommended to replace `self` with `static` for method calls (at least in Yii core code style guide).

Answer (score 1):

The Yii way to go would be to create a DB Model first, and then use it.
It is very simple to load all data from a table using models. Forget about writing plain SQL - if not absolutly needed - and use the ORM approach of Yii.

'User' is the model connected to the DB table. It looks similar to this (there may be a few more functions needed)

```
namespace app\models\db;

class User extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord {

    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'users'
    }
    ...
}
```

Check the documentation on how to [use models](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html) and how to [generate them automatically](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-gii.html), so you don't have to write everything by yourself.
Then you can use the model to retrieve data easily:

```
$users = User::find()->where(['member_type' => 'd'])->all();
```

you do not need to concert the result into an array, as you can easily use the OOP way of Yii:

```
foreach ($users as $user) {
    some_function($user->id, 'something');
}
```

This is much easier than converting to arrays, and using `for` instead of `foreach`, and getting the count of rows...
If you for some other reason would need to get the count of objects returned, you can now use only `count($users)`

As simple as that.
Maybe you should also check the [Introdcution Guide of Yii2](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/index.html) to get an overview on how to use it.

Comment: Actually, I'm lost on the User::find().... mind explaining that ? is 'User' a class inside the model?